# maximum malloc size

Tags: c, windows-7, size, malloc

I work on win7 and need to allocate 2 buffers using malloc ,each of 660M bytes
first allocation is OK,the secon buffer allocation fails.
I have 670G free mem on disk
What is maximum malloc size?And what could be the reason for above problem

Comment: Your problem is probably memory fragmentation, there is no single contiguous block large enough to satisfy 660MB.

Comment: The other possibility is that you've actually run out of memory. Unlikely on a PC, but there do exist systems with less than 1.2GB available. Maybe you're using one of them.

Comment: If your application is 32 bit, then you have a limit of 2GB per process. I'm pretty sure video card memory can eat into that, so the amount you could actually allocate may be somewhat less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum valid `malloc()` size is that is fit the state of the process heap. The heap can be fragmented (so, e.g. there's a heap with 600M free memory chunk, then 20M used chunk, then 600MB free chunk again - you just can't get 650M, although there are 1.2GB of free memory).

Moreover, AFAIK, Windows mechanism of loading DLL ties every library to a certain address, so the memory may be already fragmented by DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

You told you have 670G free memory but that is hard disk space.

The running program requires memory in **RAM** and probably your RAM memory is lower then what you require. And hence you are getting error allocating memory using malloc.